# Calling same Spring EL expressions with different root object types fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

Let's consider the following test:

```
@Test
public void testSameExpressionDifferentRootObjectClass() {
    SpelParserConfiguration config = new SpelParserConfiguration(SpelCompilerMode.IMMEDIATE, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
    SpelExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser(config);
    StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
    Expression expr = parser.parseExpression("'Test: ' + #root");

    assertThat(expr.getValue(context, 42L)).isEqualTo("Test: 42");
    assertThat(expr.getValue(context, "string")).isEqualTo("Test: string");
    assertThat(expr.getValue(context, 42L)).isEqualTo("Test: 42");
    assertThat(expr.getValue(context, "string")).isEqualTo("Test: string");
}
```

It is failing on the 3rd assertion with the following exception:

> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1072E:
>   An exception occurred whilst evaluating a compiled expression
>
> at
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:328)
>     at
>   org.example.ExpressionTest.testSameExpressionDifferentRootObjectClass(ExpressionProvidersTest.java:36)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast
>   to java.lang.String   at spel.Ex2.getValue(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:318)
>     ... 31 more

This is unexpected to me and found nothing in the documentation about this constraint. Did I do anything wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `MIXED` mode for cases like that; see the javadocs...

```
public enum SpelCompilerMode {

    /**
     * The compiler is switched off; this is the default.
     */
    OFF,

    /**
     * In immediate mode, expressions are compiled as soon as possible (usually after 1 interpreted run).
     * If a compiled expression fails it will throw an exception to the caller.
     */
    IMMEDIATE,

    /**
     * In mixed mode, expression evaluation silently switches between interpreted and compiled over time.
     * After a number of runs the expression gets compiled. If it later fails (possibly due to inferred
     * type information changing) then that will be caught internally and the system switches back to
     * interpreted mode. It may subsequently compile it again later.
     */
    MIXED

}
```